# Magento - How to add Telephone and FAX in Account Create

Tags: php, magento, input, e-commerce

I added the fields of telephone and FAX in the customer base in the url (/ customer / account / create /)

The fields are being displayed normally, what happens is that when the customer fills these fields and creates the account, when I access the admin tab manage customer data (phone and FAX) are not displayed.

I think that is not being written to the database correctly.

Anyone know what was missing?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just created inputs and label in phtml page i guess but did not have connectivity with the database.

Please check my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868175/magento-customer-attributes-with-signup-form/13868259#13868259)
this might help just create two attribute for customer Fax and telephone using the extension

you will achieve the task.

Best of luck.